# How to use AND and NOT both in single grep command

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, grep

I'm creating one of shell script, In which, I need to filter process except own grep process. If I use :

```
echo "step1"
psout=`ps -aux | grep 'deluged'| grep '58846'`
echo "step2"
echo $psout       
...
```

then stop the script means *step2* not display ! and $psout, output blank.I don't why.

If I trying use for AND and except *color*:

```
$ ps -aux | grep -e 'deluged' -e '58846' -v "color"
grep: color: No such file or directory
```

If I trying to use Keychain :

```
ps -aux | grep -e "[d]eluged"."58846"

Blank OUTPUT
```

In short, How to find process with single grep with AND and except own grep process ?

Comment: What is the exact output you'd like to see?

Comment: @Arronical In script,I need to find process with "deluged" and "58846" except grep own process.

Comment: Yes, but do you just want the PID, do you want a whole line like "/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/deluged --port=58846"?

Comment: @Arronical I need Process is exist or not

Comment: Does not `ps aux | grep '[d]eluged'` work?

Comment: OK, so what would you like to be the value of the psout variable?

Comment: what is 58846 ? if it's PID, you won't get it - it changes with each instance of command.

Comment: if echo "test2" then echo $psout, output _test2_ not display, obviously output of psout not showing and _ps aux | grep '[d]eluged'_ gives with match "deluged" and output 2-3 process.

Comment: @Serg I think 58846 refers to a port number.

Comment: posted answer, please review

Answer (score 6):

You have said in comments that you want to know if process exists or not. Use `pgrep -f 'deluge'` for that. Or alternatively `pgrep -f 'deluge.*58846'`

pgrep is specifically designed to just give you pid if process exists and avoid parsing issues with grep and ps. If process  doesn't exist, then you will have blank output

You can also use `sudo netstat -tulpan` and use grep to see if your port number is among open ones

Comment: So much more succinct than my rambling method!

Comment: @Arronical your method is proper as well. OP just needs to know if process exists, so both methods would work.

Comment: It working on command line but not working in shell script; _isproex=`pgrep -f '$1.python'`_ then echo $isproex and echo _step2_. output: not showing isproex even _step2_

Comment: it's not working because it's inside single quotes. it literally searches for `$1.python` process. Use double quotes. Then it should work

Comment: also, use `isproex=$( pgrep -f "$1.python" )`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ps aux | grep processname | grep -v 'grep'`

The first `grep` selects all lines containing the processname, the second `grep` removes the *grep-line* from the output

Comment: If I used grep output of grep getting blank as above my question

Comment: what is the output, if you skip thesecond `grep`? So just running `ps aux | grep processname`.

Comment: If I use double grep then script not work after this(ps -aux ....) command; see my question, echo _step2_  not showing. I think It's occur exception...

Comment: does the command `ps aux | grep deluged` result in two lines (the deluged process and the grep process) or something else?

Comment: As above, getting 3-4 line, one of grep own process.

Comment: The command from my answer should then result in the same lines, except for the grep process. If you still have multiple lines then and need only one, you have to use a third grep.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `-v` is not an except option, it actually means that matches are inverted. So you will print all lines that **do not match** 'deluged' and '58846'.

The error message is generated as `-v` doesn't accept arguments, so the `grep` command is trying to operate on the file "color".

To achieve the desired outcome you should use the `pgrep` command piped to grep instead:

```
pgrep  -a 'deluged' | grep -e '58846'
```

This will output a line including the PID and full command for a deluged process with the number 58846 in the command.

If you want the variable `psout` to contain 0, or any other chosen string, if the command is successful then:

```
psout=$((pgrep -a deluged | grep 58846) > /dev/null && echo "0")
echo $psout
0
```

Comment: It's give two line like " /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/deluged" and "/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/deluged --port=58846" and If I used  grep output of grep getting blank as above my question.

Comment: It may working on command line but not work shell script; On this command automatic exit on script means if i echo after this will not showing.

Comment: This will work in a Bash shell script. I don't understand what you mean by "automatic exit on script means if I echo after this will not showing". If you mean that once leaving the script, for whatever reason, `echo $psout` does not output 0, that is bacause the variable will not be set outside the environment of the shell script anyway. You can't set a variable inside a shell script, and use it outside that script on the command line, at least not this simply.

Comment: It' worked but problem is that, If match success then bash script work well but if get not match/output on psout then leaving script, I've also check null using if [ -z $psout] but getting error : like  _too many arguments_; my question is, Why leave on script.(Not execute command after this )